# Symfony search form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, hardcode, zend-lucene

I use symfony 1.4.12 with Zend Lucene. And I make custom search, I have field like category, country...I create module and I have MysearchSucess.php and there I write hardcode, like :

```
<select name="ads_country" id="ads_country">
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>
```

etc... But there are in symfony nice widget like sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCountry;
Or for examle, if user add category, I will need to add new category in code manualy... Is it possible to use widgets in my case? how to organize it right without hardcode?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I read **[this](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation)** and all ok!